# Using C++ in Visual Studio Community 2017 on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on my Mac recently, hoping to use it to program in C++. It appeared to install correctly, no errors occurred, but it seems to be missing support for C++. It will only allow me to make projects using C# and F#; I don't see C++ anywhere.

Searching around, many people suggest opening up the Visual Studio Installer and add "C++ Tools" to VS.  However, when I open up the visual studio installer, I only see the necessary packages to develop in Android, IOS, .NET, MacOS, and Xamarin.

Where is C++? Do I need to configure visual studio some other way to be able to use it for C++?

Comment: From https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/ Mac version does not support C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From these links
- https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/ 
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c879ea3b-e834-402a-847c-8214078beaa1/visual-studio-for-mac-c-empty-project?forum=visualstudiogeneral

VS Mac does not support C++

Comment: The moderator on the second link said specifically that the visual studio version for Mac does not support C++, it only supports "
    Mobile with .NET: Android, iOS, tvOS, watchOS
    Mac desktop apps
    .NET Core applications
    ASP.NET Core Web applications
    Cross-platform Unity games" I find this really disappointing. Who at microsoft decided they didn't need to include support for one of the most (if not the most) popular programming language in the world?

Answer (score 1):

Check into this article on VS Code for Mac:
[VS Code for Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Talks about coding in C++ on Mac and how to install, configure, use, debug with etc. Haven't tried it personally.

Comment: OP is referring to Visual Studio for Mac, which is definitely not the same thing as Visual Studio Code.  The former is a port of Xamarin Studio to the Mac.  The latter is an Electron-based source code editor, with extensions to make it an IDE.  Pretty much the only two things they have in common are "Visual Studio" is in the name, and they're both developed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As @Saad stated, there is no support for C++ on Visual Studio 2017 for macOS.

If you want to program in C++ in macOS, you can go with Xcode.